# How to use 2to3 to translate all files in a directory

Tags: python, python-2to3

I'm able to translate one file. But I don't understand how to translate whole directory. From docs:

```
To translate an entire project from one directory tree to another use:
$ 2to3 --output-dir=python3-version/mycode -W -n python2-version/mycode
```

Can you give me a concrete example? I have python2 files in `D:\Dir1` and want to get new files in `D:\Dir2`. I'm now in the command prompt inside `Dir1` typing `c:\Users\........\Python36\Tools\scripts\2to3.py -w`

So what is the command that should I use?

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [`FOR`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop. Or just provide the directory and the script does it automatically?

Comment: To convert all python 2 files in a directory to 3, you simply could run `$ C:\Program Files\Python\Tools\Scripts\2to3.py -w .` inside the directory that you want to translate. It would skip all the non `.py` files anyway, and remove the `-w` flag, if you don't want the backup file,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

```
D:\Dir1> c:\Users........\Python36\Tools\scripts\2to3.py --output-dir=D:\Dir2 -W -n .\
```

Notice that it is a `-W` (capital `W`).

---

As an example, I ran the script from my home directory:

```
┌─[hjpotter92:Hedwig]─[C:\Users\hjpotter92]
└──$ "C:\Program Files\Python\Tools\Scripts\2to3.py" -o Downloads\newFoo -W -n Downloads\Foo
```

Comment: At least one file or directory argument required.

Comment: @Dork what happens when you use `%CD%` instead of ``.\`` at the end?